# What is the symbol of end of a proof?

Tags: symbols, lyx, theorems

I'm trying to put a black square at the end of a proof, but is not the same as LyX gives me (when I choose "proof" at the menu).

It's different from the `\blacksquare` command (see pic below).

The square of the "end of proof" is smaller and clearer....

[image]

So, there is any way to get the square of the end of a proof and by choosing "Proof" from the menu?

Comment: What module are you adding to your document settings (Document > Settings... > Modules)?

Comment: @Werner - nothing... The box of "Selected" is empty....

Comment: What options do you have to choose from in your list of paragraph settings? Is there a "Theorem" and/or "Proof" option?

Comment: Yes, I have both... But it doesn't help me... :-(

Comment: What `\documentclass` (Document > Settings... > Document Class) are you using?

Comment: "Hebrew Article" (I'm writing a document at Hebrew)....

Comment: @Yoar by the way, please provide a minimal example in the future.  Werner's questions would have been answered if you had just provided an example. For more information, see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Hebrew Article` document class uses `\rule{2mm}{2mm}` for it's `proof` environment "QED symbol". To see this, open the View > Source Pane and choose, for example, "Preamble only" to see

```
\newenvironment{proof}%
{\R{\textbf{הוכחה:}}}%
{\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}\par\vspace{2mm}}
```

You could add to your preamble

```
\newcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{2mm}{2mm}}
```

which would allow you to insert some ERT with `\qedsymbol` to get the same output as with other Proofs.

Comment: It's works!! Thank you!! BTW - I can play with the size of the square, right? (And I insert it at math mode....)

Comment: @Yoar: Yes. If you want to change the original `proof` environment you can do so using `\renewenvironment{proof}` and update the `\rule` usage.

Comment: How can I update it (after I'm write `\renewenvironment{proof}` )? Where I'm doing this? Thank you!

Comment: @Yoar: Just copy the first code snippet from Werners answer to you preamble and use `\renewenvironment` instead of `\newenv…`. In the third line replace `\rule{2mm}{2mm}` by what ever suits you. I suggest replacing it by `\qedsymbol` if you want to use it anywhere else too. In that case changing the definition of `\qedsymbol` later would also apply to `{proof}` and your document stays consistent.